# Why am I getting Segmentation Fault (core dumped)?

Tags: segmentation-fault, c++14

It compiles fine, but upon execution I'm getting "Segmentation Fault (core Dumped)". Doing some quick googling tells me that trying to access non existent memory but im not sure where! Below is the CPP file:

```
        #include "A2Q1.h"
        using namespace std;
        int main() {
        QUEUE *myQ = 0;
        QUEUE *newQ = 0;

        myQ = createQueue(myQ); //creates a queue
        newQ = createQueue(newQ);

        addElement(myQ, 'L'); 
        addElement(myQ, 'a');
        addElement(myQ, 'k');
        addElement(myQ, 'e');
        addElement(myQ, 'h');
        addElement(myQ, 'e');
        addElement(myQ, 'a');
        addElement(myQ, 'd');
        addElement(myQ, ' ');

        addElement(newQ, 'U'); 
        addElement(newQ, 'n');
        addElement(newQ, 'i');
        addElement(newQ, 'v');
        addElement(newQ, 'e');
        addElement(newQ, 'r');
        addElement(newQ, 's');
        addElement(newQ, 'i');
        addElement(newQ, 't');
        addElement(newQ, 'y');

        catQueue(myQ, newQ);
        return 0;
    }
```

Below is the Header File:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>//for malloc

#define MAXQUEUE 25      
typedef char QUEUE_NODE; 

typedef struct Node {
 QUEUE_NODE data;      
 struct Node *next;  
 }node;

typedef struct QUEUE {
int count;
node *front;       //will point to first element in node
node *rear;        //points to most recent aded node
}queue;

QUEUE* createQueue(QUEUE *q)//pointer to queue created in main
{
q = (QUEUE*)malloc(sizeof(QUEUE));
if (q)                   //if memory available for q
{
q->front = 0;     //initialize it all to NULL
q->rear = 0;
q->count = 0;        //no elements to count yet
}
printf("successfully created a queue.\n\n");
return q;
}

bool addElement(QUEUE *q, char dataPtr) //enqueue element
{

node *newPtr; //contains data & next

if (!(newPtr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)))) 
return false;
newPtr->data = dataPtr; //letter in dataPtr now placed in queue
newPtr->next = 0; 
if (q->count == 0) //if this is the first element in queue
q->front = newPtr;
else
q->rear->next = newPtr;
(q->count)++; //because new element added
q->rear = newPtr; //new element is placed at rear
return true;
}

bool catQueue(QUEUE *sameQ,QUEUE *addQ)
{
node *tempPtr; //contains data and next

if (!(tempPtr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)))) /
return false;

tempPtr = sameQ->front; //tempPtr points to front of queue
sameQ->rear->next = addQ->front;

printf("Concatonated queue:\n\n");
while (tempPtr->data != 0)
{
printf("%c", tempPtr->data);
tempPtr = tempPtr->next;
}
return true;
}

bool delElement(QUEUE *q, char itemPtr) //dequeue element
{
node *deleteLoc; //has data and next
if (!q->count) //if no elements execute
return false; //because queue is empty
itemPtr = q->front->data; //contains data @ front of queue
printf("%c", itemPtr);
deleteLoc = q->front; //points to first node
if (q->count == 1)
else
q->front = q->front->next; 
(q->count)--;
free(deleteLoc); 
return true;
}

int queueCount(QUEUE *q) 
{
return q->count;
}

QUEUE *destroyQueue(QUEUE *q) //destroys queue
{
node *delPtr; //deletion pointer

if (q)
{
while (q->front != 0) //while there are still elements in queue
{
    q->front->data = 0; //removes data from node
    delPtr = q->front; //points to first location in queue
    q->front = q->front->next; 
    free(delPtr); //deletes current front node
    }
    free(q); //deletes entire queue
    }
    printf("queue successully deleted\n\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small bug in your A2Q1.h header

In catQueue function ... the condition in while loop

Your's is

```
tempPtr->data!=0
```

it should be

```
tempPtr->next!=0
```

and you should probably use

```
new and delete
```

operator instead of

```
malloc and free
```